# Pagination in angular

Tags: angular, angular-pagination

I'm using ngx-pagination

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination
>
> app.module:

```
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   ...
  ],
  imports: [  
    ...
    NgxPaginationModule,
   
  ],
```

> .ts file

```
  p: Number = 1;
  count: Number = 2;
```

> Component:

```
 <li *ngFor="let data of this.lists; let i = index  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> # {{ i+1 }} Test</a></li>
```

Getting this error :

> error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token | at column 50 in [let
> data of this.lists; let i = index  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count,
> currentPage: p }] in ....component.html@67:32

Any solution to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
<li *ngFor="let data of this.lists | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p } index as i"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> # {{ i+1 }} Test</a></li>
```